# Changing the color of a div when you click it twice?

Tags: javascript, background-color

I have a link with an onClick command to change the background color. When you click it the color changes fine, but how can I make it so when you click it again the background color changes to normal?

```
onClick="style.backgroundColor='#3E729F';"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might define a function in a script element :

```
<script>
var oldColor;
function switchColor(el) {
   if (oldColor) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = oldColor;
        oldColor = null;
   } else {
       oldColor = el.style.backgroundColor;
       el.style.backgroundColor = '#3E729F';
   }
}
</script>
```

and call it like this :

```
onclick="switchColor(this);"
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EwaCW/1/)

Comment: That will change if you click it once.. I assume he wants to change the color when he clicks the div twice. (Have a counter maybe?)

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to be working... 

Normally it starts off with no background, then when you click it the background should change to #3E729F. With this, however, the only options are for it to change to the new color and stay that way, or stay with no background.

Comment: @Richie Lews was right, I forgot one thing. See edited version.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add or remove a background color, you can check if the element has a background color.

```
<script>
function highlight(e) {
    if (e.style.backgroundColor) {
        e.style.backgroundColor = null;
    } else {
        e.style.backgroundColor = "#ffa";
    }
}
</script>
<div onclick="highlight(this);">a</div>
<div onclick="highlight(this);">a</div>
```